# Search for a number in an array - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Alright.. I have been trying to make this code work, but for some reason it doesn't and I cannot seem to find the issue. Can someone clear it out? It's supposed to run 5 numbers, and you should then enter a desired number you'd like to know whether exist or not in the array. It just keeps saying no.

```
void search_for_number(int *a, int search);

int main(void)
{
  int number[5];
  int i, search, a = 1;

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    printf("Number %d of 5: \n", a++);
    scanf("%d", &number[i]);
  }

  printf("\nWhat number should we search for?: \n");
  scanf("%d", &search);

  search_for_number(&number[i], search);
}

void search_for_number(int *a, int search)
{
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    if(*a == search)
    {
      printf("%d is present!\n", search);
    }
  }

  if(*a != search)
  {
    printf("%d is not present.\n", search);
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `search_for_number(&number[i], search);` to `search_for_number(number, search);`

Comment: You  should read how arrays are sent to functions, and how they should be accessed.

Comment: @EdHeal, There are other problems too..

Comment: First one off the top of my head

Comment: Add `return;` after `printf("%d is present!\n", search);`

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any numbers put in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send an array to a function, you need to send the base address of the array and receive it with a pointer.

```
search_for_number(&number[i], search);
```

In this line, `i = 5` since you did not reset it after the `for` loop.

Either reset it before calling the function, or you can simply do

```
search_for_number(number, search);
```

Since the name of the array is the base address itself.

---

Another issue is the way you are accessing the array in the function.

In the function `search_for_number()` since `a` is now pointing to the first integer of the array, you can access them by doing `a[i]`, which basically means `*(a + i)`. So, after the changes it should look like,

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(a[i] == search)     // or if(*(a + i) == search)
    {
        printf("%d is present!\n", search);
    }
}
```

**Do the changes accordingly in other places too.**

---

And, since you want to end the function execution after you have found an element, you need to make the function return after it has found,

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(a[i] == search)      // or if(*(a + i) == search)
    {
        printf("%d is present!\n", search);
        return;
    }
}
```

---

Btw, since you added the `return;` statement in the first loop, you don't need the next check. So, your total function should look like

```
void search_for_number(int *a, int search)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == search)      // or if(*(a + i) == search)
        {
            printf("%d is present!\n", search);
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("%d is not present.\n", search);
}
```

---

Your `main()` has a return value, so do add

```
return 0;
```

in the end of `main()`. It nay be omitted, but it is a good coding practice. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c).

Comment: `return 0;` for `main` is implicit.

Comment: Everything makes so much more sense now! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 1):

The function `search_for_number` is called passing to it the address of the non-existent element with index 5 of the array

```
search_for_number(&number[i], search);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

So this call does not make sense.

And this statement within the function `search_for_number`

```
if(*a == search)
```

or this statement

```
if(*a != search)
```

always compares the first element of the array with value `search`.

Also it is a bad idea that the function depends on magic number 5.:)

The function can be written the following way

```
void search_for_number( const int *a, int n, int search )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < n && a[i] != search ) i++;

    if ( i != n )
    {
        printf( "%d is present!\n", search );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d is not present.\n", search );
    }
}
```

and called like

```
search_for_number( number, 5, search );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void search_for_number( const int *a, int n, int search )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < n && a[i] != search ) i++;

    if ( i != n )
    {
        printf( "%d is present!\n", search );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d is not present.\n", search );
    }
}

#define N   5

int main( void )
{
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for ( int i = 0; i <= N + 1; i++ ) search_for_number( a, N, i );
}
```

Its output is

```
0 is not present.
1 is present!
2 is present!
3 is present!
4 is present!
5 is present!
6 is not present.
```

Of course it would be better that the second parameter had type `size_t` instead of `int`.:) For example

```
void search_for_number( const int *a, size_t n, int search );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing things out. Everything makes great sense now :D